# Laravel 5.2 trying to get user_id post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am following a Laravel course on Udemy and while I followed everything the instructor did, for some weird reason I am not getting the expected result.

This is the Relationship One to One lesson and I added a function in User Model to check if it has any posts.

Then added the route to display post if user_id equals.

app\User.php

```
public function post() {

    return $this->hasOne('App\Post');

}
```

app\Http\routes.php

```
    Route::get('/user/{id}/post', function($id) {

    return User::find($id)->post;

});
```

Below is the screenshot from the database showing that I have a post with user_id = 1 in the posts table. I also have a user with id=1 in the user's table.
[MySQL data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okq3V.png)
Why do I get a blank page when visiting domain/user/1/post?

Sohel, i got a result from your function, but had to use

```
var_dump(User::with('post')->where('id',1)->first());
```

Then tried something else:

```
return User::with('post')->where('id',$id)->first();
```

And this is the result:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Nick","email":"nick@kriogen.name","created_at":"2018-03-15 09:49:51","updated_at":"2018-03-15 09:49:51","post":null}
```

Comment: Did you check `laravel.log` file for any errors?

Comment: No error in log. Also, it would display an error if i had one, however, all i get is a blank page and no error in log file.

Comment: Try `return $this->hasOne('App\Post', 'post_id', 'id');`. Also, enable error reporting if you want to see errors.

Comment: please show what `dd(User::with('post')->where('id',1)->first())` gives

Comment: Debug is on:
APP_DEBUG=true

Tried this: return $this->hasOne('App\Post', 'post_id', 'id'); // same result, blank page, no error.

Comment: For me, a "white page" in Laravel was mostly due to the webserver not being able to write to `storage/logs/laravel.log`. Make sure your webserver has permission to write to it

Comment: On the basis that the log does have entries like this one, i would say it has the rights to write to it.
#50 /home/ec2-user/environment/cms/server.php(21): require_once('/home/ec2-user/...')
#51 {main}

Comment: @KriogenMihalcea show what `dd(User::with('post')->where('id',1)->first())` gives

Comment: couldn't use dd, but used vad_dump and this is the result:

object(App\User)#157 (24) { ["fillable":protected]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "name" [1]=> string(5) "email" [2]=> string(8) "password" } ["hidden":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "password" [1]=> string(14) "remember_token" } ["conn

Comment: please add this on question

Comment: I realized you have a field `deleted_at` in your posts table, which should mean you are using "Soft deletion". Not sure if the default for undeleted models is `NULL` or like in your case `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Could you try to use [withTrashed()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting) in your query? Can you actually get only the post from your db?

Comment: Sorry, just figured it out and added as answer exactly what you said and then saw your comment. Thank you, yes, that was the issue i was having.

Answer (score 0):

Your one to one relationship should go as:
app\User.php

```
public function post() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Post');
}
```

app\Post.php

```
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\User');
}
```

you can try doing this function in controller:

```
public function getPost {
    $user= User::find($id);
    return $user->post();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with the functions, the issue was in the database.
Column deleted_at was not NULL and it was marking the post as being soft deleted, therefore not being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the "user_id" field is in the "posts" table, the relation in the App\User model need to be:

```
public function post() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

then, call it without the parenthesis to get the result:

```
public function getPost {
    $user= User::find($id);
    return $user->post;
}
```

When you use the parenthesis, you get the builder and not the result. example:

```
public function getPost {
    $user= User::find($id);
    return $user->post()->get();
}
```

OR

```
public function getPost {
    $user= User::find($id);
    return $user->post()->where('name', 'like', '%hello%')->get();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need `->hasMany()` relation if you want to check if user has any posts because the user can has many posts... and the code would be:

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

The call:

```
User::find($id)->posts;
```

Comment: Well, the whole point of this is the One to One relation, therefore, i have 1 user, 1 post with that user's ID.
Why would i check if he has more than 1 if i know he doesn't?

Also tried it your way, and all I get is: [] which means it wants to show an array of posts, but it has no posts to display.

Comment: is your user id field named 'user_id'? Check laravel doc's where to please db field names like hasOne('App\Post', 'user_id')